# Team Explorer window sometimes not shows changeset number

Tags: visual-studio-2012, team-explorer

When I chekin some changes, sometimes at the top of team explorer window I can see link to changeset, I can click on it and, for example, request review. But sometimes this link does not appear, and I have to go to Solution Explorer/History to find my changeset.

Why does it work different? What scenario? How can i have this link after every chekin?

Here is the screenshot of link ("Changeset 37957") I talking about:

[image: team Explorer link to changeset after chekin]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of what you're talking about?

Comment: I got nothing. Do you have a gated check-in? Or some other kind of check-in policy?

Comment: @aclear16 no, only policy we have is chekin comment required

Comment: @JesonMartajaya can you find stable scenario?

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this same intermittent behavior if you have more than one TFS server defined on the "Connect to Team Foundation Server" dialog.

If you don't need more than one server, remove all others.
  * After you remove those, you must close ALL your VS instances and clear the TFS cache (that is, delete all files and folders under "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\4.0\Cache" or whichever TFS cache folder you have defined ).

Then retry.

Comment: it's very interesting idea! I really have two TFS servers defined. I will delete the old one and investigate this problem. Thank you.

Comment: I've deleted second tfs and still have this behaviour :(

Comment: I edited my answer with more details (TFS cache deletion). Try again.